# Sticky navbar - Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, nav, sticky

I want to have a sticky navbar on my website, which should stick to the top of the page after the user scroll over the header.

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/df8tb/1849/

Here is the main code:

```
.goToTop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 1;
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var navHeight = 100; // custom nav height
    ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) ? $('nav').addClass('goToTop') : $('nav').removeClass('goToTop');
  });
});
```

But it doesn't really work.

My question is how can I fix the behavior that when the user scroll there is a 'jumping' (The content goes up)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/augburto/df8tb/1851/

There are two main things you need to fix.

One thing is your `navHeight` isn't exactly where the navigation is. What you want is the location of your `nav` in respect to the viewport top. You can do that by doing.

```
var navTop = $('#nav').offset().top;
```

I changed the naming convention because its more accurate to say its the `navTop` rather than the height.

Your other issue where the content jumps is because when you set the navigation to `position: fixed`, it takes it out of the document flow. One way of getting around this is to calculate the actual height of the `nav` and then set the position to offset it by that much when the navigation gets stickied.

```
var navHeight = $('#nav').height();
$('#content').css('top', navHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of sticking the nav bar when you have scrolled the "navBar height", do it when you have scrolled the "header" height (or header height PLUS its padding + margins)

Comment: The header height is 100px in the example

Answer (score 0):

Your styling should be like this.
`.goToTop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 70px;
    width:100%;

    z-index: 2000;
}`
Why I changed z-index to 2000 is because bootstrap assigns z-index of 1000, 1020 etc for certain elements. So if you want this on top of all that, your z-index should be 2000.

And your script should be like this
`$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $(window).scroll(function(){
         var navHeight = 100;
         if($(this).scrollTop() > navHeight ){
             $('nav').addClass('goToTop');
         }
         else{
             $('nav').removeClass('goToTop');
         }
     });
});`

Comment: Earlier, I haven't seen your code in jsfiddle. But checked it now. Seems like you have used `container` class for the parent divs. it would be better if you use `container-fluid` since it would span to the full width.

Answer (score 0):

Because you changed the `nav` to `fixed`, it no longer has collision (layout, whatever). So we need to compensate for the extra space. We can do this by padding the top of your content.

```
.addSpace {
    padding-top : 60px;
}
```

Now all we have to do is update your JavaScript to put this class onto the things you want to pad:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
        var navHeight = 100; // custom nav height
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
            $('nav').addClass('goToTop');
            $('#content').addClass('addSpace');
        } else {
            $('nav').removeClass('goToTop');
            $('#content').removeClass('addSpace');
        }
    });
});
```

and it [works perfectly](http://jsfiddle.net/df8tb/1853/)! (I added a `#content` id to the content element, but you can use any selector you can think of).